# HighCharts Add Comments

Tags: jquery, highcharts

If we use http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ as an example. How would I go about letting a user add comments to a particular facet (or the whole of) the graph? Let's say they click anywhere in the graph, how can I set it up so they can add a comment.

Then when the graph is refreshed, the comment(s) are visible or at least the points where they were clicked

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [annotations](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations) plugin, which allows to add a text in any place of chart.

Comment: Nice - can't see any obvious way to save the data though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`chart.renderer`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer).

Would this be saved somehow such that another user looking at the site sees the comments? If so you are are better setting up a backend as well. So that when user A creates a note it is saved in some form (db would be prefered at least for me). And then, when user B goes to the site and loads the chart, it allows the display of the new annotated item.

Comment: To allow saving you would have to grab what the path is that the user wants annotated and save it. Many ways to skin a cat for that.